# Inner Relative Layout Not getting below as defined and missing controls

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"                       
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                    >   
            <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/default1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                        android:background="@drawable/default1"

                        android:scaleType="fitXY">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/postscore"
                        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                        android:layout_width="180dp" 
                        android:layout_height="45dp" 

                        android:src="@drawable/fc_postyour_best_score_bg"                       
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY">
            </ImageView>   




            <ToggleButton 
                         android:id="@+id/fsvibrate_on"
                         android:layout_width="135dp"
                         android:layout_height="35dp"

                         android:textOff=""
                         android:textOn=""

                         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                         android:background="@drawable/fsvibrate_on">
            </ToggleButton>

            <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/fcplaydown"
                        android:layout_width="215dp" 
                        android:layout_height="53dp" 
                        android:background="@drawable/button1"

                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">
            </ImageButton>
            <RelativeLayout 
                        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                      
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/fcplaydown"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fcplaydown"
                        >

            <ToggleButton 
                        android:id="@+id/fcsoundondown"
                        android:layout_width="101dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"                        
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:textOn=""
                        android:background="@drawable/fcsoundondown">
            </ToggleButton>

            <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/fchelpdown"
                        android:layout_width="103dp" 
                        android:layout_height="53dp" 

                        android:background="@drawable/fchelpdown"   
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fcsoundondown"                  

                        >
            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/fcboards_down"
                        android:layout_width="101dp"
                        android:layout_height="55dp"    
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"                                         
                        android:layout_below="@id/fcsoundondown"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fcsoundondown"
                        android:background="@drawable/fcleaderboards_down">

            </ImageButton >    

            <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/fcments_down"
                        android:layout_width="103dp" 
                        android:layout_height="53dp" 

                        android:background="@drawable/fcachivements_down"   
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fcboards_down"                  

                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/fchelpdown">
            </ImageButton>
            </RelativeLayout>



            <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="48dp" 
                        android:background="@drawable/android"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/default1">


                            </ImageView> 

        </RelativeLayout>
```

I have 2 problems

1. The RelativeLayout02 is not getting below as defined but it is comming after `@+id/postscore`
2. I can not see `@+id/fcsoundondown"` and `@+id/fcboards_down`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such id **fcleaderboards_down** and you have used it inside the image button `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fcleaderboards_down"`.

Comment: okk that's may mistake I renamed that Imagebutto ID but I forgot to change there in the stack over flow ...But the problem is still there.